# Should I worry about precision when I use C++ mathematical functions with integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy

For example, The code below will give undesirable result due to precision of floating point numbers.

```
double a = 1 / 3.0;
int b = a * 3;      // b will be 0 here
```

I wonder whether similar problems will show up if I use mathematical functions. For example

```
int a = sqrt(4);       // Do I have guarantee that I will always get 2 here?
int b = log2(8);       // Do I have guarantee that I will always get 3 here?
```

If not, how to solve this problem?

Edit:

Actually, I came across this problem when I was programming for an algorithm task. There I want to get

> the largest integer which is power of 2 and is less than or equal to integer **N**

So round function can not solve my problem. I know I can solve this problem through a loop, but it seems not very elegant.

I want to know if

```
int a = pow(2, static_cast<int>(log2(N)));
```

can always give correct result. For example if N==8, is it possible that log2(N) gives me something like 2.9999999999999 and the final result become 4 instead of 8?

Comment: I suspect it would depend entirely on your application.  Sometimes you don't want anything after the ".".  Sometimes you do

Comment: The issue is more that casting a double to an int discards what is after the decimal point. So `(int)1.9999` becomes `1` and not `2` as might be expected.

Comment: @FrankeHippman, that's not true.  sqrt(4) = 2, which is representable precisely, so there's no rounding issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Inaccurate operands vs inaccurate results

> I wonder whether similar problems will show up if I use mathematical functions.

Actually, the problem that could prevent `log2(8)` to be 3 does not exist for basic operations (including `*`). But it exists for the `log2` function.

You are confusing two different issues:

```
double a = 1 / 3.0;
int b = a * 3;      // b will be 0 here
```

In the example above, `a` is not exactly 1/3, so it is possible that `a*3` does not produce `1.0`. The product could have happened to round to `1.0`, it just doesn't. However, if `a` somehow had been exactly 1/3, the product of `a` by 3 would have been exactly `1.0`, because **this is how IEEE 754 floating-point works**: the result of basic operations is the nearest representable value to the mathematical result of the same operation on the same operands. When the exact result is representable as a floating-point number, then that representation is what you get.

### Accuracy of sqrt and log2

`sqrt` is part of the “basic operations”, so `sqrt(4)` is guaranteed **always, with no exception, in an IEEE 754 system**, to be `2.0`.

`log2` is not part of the basic operations. The result of an implementation of this function is not guaranteed by the IEEE 754 standard to be the closest to the mathematical result. It can be another representable number further away. So without more hypotheses on the `log2` function that you use, it is impossible to tell what `log2(8.0)` can be.

However, most implementations of reasonable quality for elementary functions such as `log2` guarantee that the result of the implementation is within 1 [ULP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) of the mathematical result. When the mathematical result is not representable, this means either the representable value above or the one below (but not necessarily the closest one of the two). When the mathematical result is exactly representable (such as `3.0`), then this representation is still the only one guaranteed to be returned.

So about `log2(8)`, the answer is “if you have a reasonable quality implementation of `log2`, you can expect the result to be 3.0`”.

Unfortunately, not every implementation of every elementary function is a quality implementation. See this [blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most), caused by a widely used implementation of `pow` being inaccurate by more than 1 ULP when computing `pow(10.0, 2.0)`, and thus returning `99.0` instead of `100.0`.

### Rounding to the nearest integer

Next, in each case, you assign the floating-point to an `int` with an implicit conversion. This conversion is defined in the C++ standard as *truncating* the floating-point values (that is, rounding towards zero). If you expect the result of the floating-point computation to be an integer, you can round the floating-point value to the **nearest** integer before assigning it. It will help obtain the desired answer in all cases where the error does not accumulate to a value larger than 1/2:

```
int b = std::nearbyint(log2(8.0));
```

To conclude with a straightforward answer to the question the the title: yes, you should worry about accuracy when using floating-point functions for the purpose of producing an integral end-result. These functions do not come even with the guarantees that basic operations come with.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I want to keep the truncating behavior. You can see my EDIT for more detail.

Comment: @delphifirst It seems to me that the answer already answers “I want to know if `int a = pow(2, static_cast<int>(log2(N)));` can always give correct result”. The answer is “yes for a quality implementation of `pow` and `log2`. No for a crappy implementation of either `log2` or `pow`. Some implementations of `pow` out there are crappy. Here is a link: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/06/Non-experts-need-accurate-floating-point-the-most ”. All this information is already in the answer and I do not see anything else I could say to help.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Both you and the OP are fixating on the case where int(log2(i)) is too small, when i == 2^k. But there is also the case where i = 2^k - e, for some small e, and int(log2(i)) is too big because the value of log2(i) is rounded to the nearest representable value, which happens to be k. If the implementation of log2 respects rounding modes, you could set the rounding mode to FE_DOWNWARD or FE_TOWARDZERO, but there are no guarantees either way. See http://ideone.com/X7m5B0

Comment: ... It doesn't take a sophisticated numerical analysis to show that log2(2^53-1) is closer to 53 than to the next smaller floating point number. There are 2^52 integers between 2^52 and 2^53, but only 2^47 double-precision floating point values between 52 and 53. Furthermore, the logs of consecutive integers get closer together as the integers get bigger, so we'd expect that more than 16 integers will have logs which correctly round to 53.

Comment: @rici This answer is “fixating” on the case where the result of the floating-point function is applied to arguments for which the result is exactly representable, because out of two examples in the question, two are of this form. You are right. Most `log2` implementation are not correctly rounded for any rounding mode (not that one is easier than the others). All implementation that I know of that are correctly rounded expect the FPU to be set to nearest-even, but may allow you to call a rounding-down variant (`log2_rd` in CRlibm).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I tried the example program (on the ideone link) with `fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO)` and it did indeed give me a value of log2 rounded toward zero. But that's just one datapoint. I understand that the answer derives from the examples in the question, but the actual question is more general. I contend that your comment above "The answer is 'yes for a quality implementation'" at least needs to be qualified for the range of `i` for which it will work, and subject to rounding mode also because of loss of precision casting a 64-bit integer to a double.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the default conversion from a floating point number to integer in C++ is really crazy as it works by dropping the decimal part.

This is bad for two reasons:

1. a floating point number really really close to a positive integer, but below it will be converted to the previous integer instead (e.g. 3-1×10<sup>-10</sup> = 2.9999999999 will be converted to 2)
2. a floating point number really really close to a negative integer, but above it will be converted to the next integer instead (e.g. -3+1×10<sup>-10</sup> = -2.9999999999 will be converted to -2)

The combination of (1) and (2) means also that using `int(x + 0.5)` will not work reasonably as it will round negative numbers up.

There is a reasonable `round` function, but unfortunately returns another floating point number, thus you need to write `int(round(x))`.

When working with C99 or C++11 you can use `lround(x)`.

Note that the only numbers that can be represented correctly in floating point are quotients where the denominator is an integral power of 2.

For example `1/65536 = 0.0000152587890625` can be represented correctly, but even just `0.1` is impossible to represent correctly and thus any computation involving that quantity will be approximated.

Of course when using 0.1 approximations can cancel out leaving a correct result occasionally, but even just adding ten times 0.1 will not give 1.0 as result when doing the computation using IEEE754 double-precision floating point numbers.

Even worse the compilers are allowed to use **higher** precision for intermediate results. This means that adding 10 times 0.1 **may** give back 1 when converted to an integer if the compiler decides to use higher accuracy and round to closest double at the end.

This is "worse" because despite being the precision higher the results are compiler and compiler options dependent, making reasoning about the computations harder and making the exact result non portable among different systems (even if they use the same precision and format).

Most compilers have special options to avoid this specific problem.

Comment: If you mean “3-1×10-200” as a double-precision floating-point number, this floating-point number does not exist. If you mean “3-1×10-200” as the subtraction of the floating-point numbers `3.0` and `1E-200`, the result of this floating-point subtraction definitely produces 3 when converted to an integer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: they don't exist in 64-bit (double precision), correct. I changed the example to a case working with real C++ implementations.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "crazy"; there are times when it's the right thing to do and there are times that it isn't; personally, were I designing a language, I would require that float-to-integer conversions be performed using functions which explicitly specified what to do with fractions (round, truncate, floor, or fail).  Having `intVar = (int)floatVar;` silently assign `intVar` a value which doesn't match `floatVar` doesn't seem like it's really a "type conversion".